# Using SQL Service broker vs Queues with web service

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

We have a legacy system with central database (SQL Server) and small clients (KIOSK- with local DB (SQL Express)) which is writtent using WPF application. The data sync between client and central DB is done using C#, ADO.NET sql statements. This takes huge toll on the  performance. The number of clients currently we have are 400 and it will be increasing. Each client sends 100,000 records per day to the central database.

We are planning to re-write this sync part using **SQL Service Broker**

One of the main issue, the schema between client and central DB is different. The tables were not normalized and the worst case is most of the columns were using nvarchar datatypes for storing datetime, intergers data.

I am concerned about using Service Broker as most of the business logic would be written using Stored Procedure.

I would like to get some ideas on whether using this technology would be the best or do we need to consider creating REST based service using Message Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I would recommend against using Service Broker in this kind of environment.

**Detailed answer**

While Service Broker is indeed a very lightweight and reliable communication mechanism, it was designed with a different goal in mind. Namely, it works best in a static topology, when administrators setup everything once and then the entire system runs for years, with little or no changes.

Judging by what I understood from your explanation, your network of connected hosts is much more dynamic, with hosts coming and going on a daily basis. This will incur high maintenance costs on your support, because in order to establish communication between two Service Broker endpoints belonging to different SQL Server instances, you will need (among many other things) to generate at least 1 pair of certificates and exchange their public keys between participating instances, after which they will have to be deployed in both the `master` and the subject databases on both sides.

This certificate exchange and deployment should be done before Service Broker messaging will be possible, so you will need another communication channel between the servers for the exchange to happen. Normally, this is done manually by DBAs due to high security risks associated with potential loss of transport-level keys. In your environment, however, there is a good chance that people will simply not be able to keep up. Not to mention a potential for human errors, which will be quite high due to large amount of repetitive manual work.

In short, I would recommend to look for something which is easier to deploy and maintain. [Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) might be a good start; as for transport, you have a full smorgasbord of choices, from WCF to WebAPI (to whatever else have appeared in the last few years).

Comment: Thanks Roger. I didnt think about the certificate part. As we are a small team of 5, I was worried about the maintenance and troubleshooting.